# How can we do auto exposure lock in samsung s4 similar to iphone?

Tags: camera, iphone

How can we do auto exposure lock in samsung s4 similar to iphone?
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exposure lock is a feature of the app. If this feature is not present in the native Android camera app, you need a different app. [Eight seconds with Google later](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20auto%20exposure%20lock%20camera%20app), [you get this](http://appcrawlr.com/android-apps/best-apps-exposure-lock), for example.

Comment: Thanks MoritzLost You are right i get it. we need app like Open Camera. i have installed it and it gives all features what i want.